# Client side gets status 'aborted' when trying to get CSS file

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I'm trying to surf my website.

There is a specific css file I cannot get from the server.

I get "aborted" status.

What can cause this?

Comment: Where do you see "aborted"?  Have you checked if the file is actually still there?  Details!  Help us help you =)

Comment: I wonder why some people have down-voted this excellent question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an article that might shed some light on some of the less seen status'

http://blog.httpwatch.com/2008/01/28/what-does-aborted-mean-in-httpwatch/